# KSQL consistency

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am doing a PoC using dotnet and ksql.
https://github.com/pablocastilla/kafkiano/

The overall idea is to see if I can implement business logic using KSQL. In the example I introduce devices in the stock and make orders from it. The example consists in this:

Two main streams:

- Inventory stream receives the adding event to inventory.
- Orders stream receives orders of products.

With those streams I create two tables:

- ProductStock: it just adds the products to the stock
- Orders: counts the orders by product

After those two tables I create another table with the difference between the orders and the products in the inventory, just to know if there are products left.

With a join in that last table and the order stream I can have the stock left when that order is processed.

I am introducing the events using the productname as key. So far it works well in my machine, but my questions are:

- Is this consistent in a big production environment? I would like to know restrictions about when the consistency is broken when a lot of events are received in parallel.
- How can I know which queries are executed before others? I need to count the difference between inventory and orders before the I join that difference with the order stream

Thanks

```
KSQL:
//INVENTORY STREAMS
CREATE STREAM InventoryEventsStream (ProductName VARCHAR, Quantity INT) WITH (kafka_topic='INVENTORYEVENTS', key='ProductName', value_format='json');

//TABLE GROUPING BY PRODUCT
CREATE TABLE  ProductsStock as select ProductName,sum(Quantity) as Stock from InventoryEventsStream group by ProductName;

// ORDERS STREAMS
CREATE STREAM OrdersCreatedStream (ProductName VARCHAR,Quantity INT, OrderId VARCHAR, User VARCHAR) WITH (kafka_topic='ORDERSEVENTS', key='ProductName', value_format='json');
//TABLE GROUPING BY PRODUCT
CREATE TABLE ProductsOrdered as select ProductName as ProductName,sum(Quantity) as Orders from  ORDERSCREATEDSTREAM group by ProductName;

// join with the difference
CREATE TABLE StockByProductTable  AS  SELECT ps.ProductName as ProductName,ps.Stock - op.Orders as Stock FROM PRODUCTSORDERED op JOIN ProductsStock ps ON op.ProductName = ps.ProductName;

//logic: I want the stock left when I make an order
SELECT ocs.OrderId,ocs.User,sbpt.Stock FROM OrdersCreatedStream ocs JOIN  StockByProductTable sbpt ON sbpt.ProductName = ocs.ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy and paste the [github answer](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2225) I got from the confluent team:

"I get your question. A minimal answer for your question is, it executes as soon as your message is available in the stream.

A good analogy would be a machinery which is always running.
Whenever a payload enters inside, it will just process it. Now it comes to you on the chaining part. Are you inserting some payload to a new record stream after processing? Then yes, you can call it 'chaining'. Once you run / execute CTAS/ CSAS statements you see something like 'Table/Stream created and Running' , that is exactly what it means.

You have ignited an always running query!"